# Can Sandy Bridge integrated graphics handle full Windows-7 Aero graphics?

Tags: windows-7, aero, integrated-graphics

I'm building a couple of new boxes for business not gaming.  Don't need to overclock, would love to avoid heat/noise/$ of a GPU, but I would like to have the full Win7 Aero graphics experience.  Can the integrated graphics in Sandy Bridge handle that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, the Intel HD graphics core present in Sandy Bridge processors are fine for Aero.

Comment: Agreed, we're using integrated graphics for all of our buisness machines (pre Sandy Bridge configs) and have good Aero performance.The only machines's I've not had the ability to use Aero on were some early P4 IBM desktops.

Comment: Thanks, was having a hard time finding an answer to that!

Answer (score 1):

I ran W7 and Aero on the old Intel 945GC chip, it was slow until I turned off transparency, then it ran fine, so yes the Sandy Bridge platform will run aero with no problems.

Comment: More reading on the Intel HD graphics...https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Intel+HD+sandy+bridge+graphics+performance&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=